# Copy Row(s) from One DataFrame to Another with Regex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to extract specific rows from a dataframe where values in a column contain a designated string. For example, the current dataframe looks like:

```
df1=

Location   Value   Name     Type
Up         10      Test A   X
Up         12      Test B   Y
Down       11      Prod 1   Y
Left       8       Test C   Y
Down       15      Prod 2   Y
Right      30      Prod 3   X
```

And I am trying to build a new dataframe will all rows that have "Test" in the 'Name' column.

```
df2=

Location   Value   Name     Type
Up         10      Test A   X
Up         12      Test B   Y
Left       8       Test C   Y
```

Is there a way to do this with regex or match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
df_out = df[df["Name"].str.contains("Test")]
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
  Location  Value    Name Type
0       Up     10  Test A    X
1       Up     12  Test B    Y
3     Left      8  Test C    Y
```

Answer (score 0):

How about: `df2 = df1.loc[['Test' in name for name in df1.Name ]]`